# Specific URL error redirect to proper URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I've search the DB and found similar solutions to the following but they don't seem to be working. Here's the issue: We thought we were being clever by adding a QR code to our business cards.

A smart phone QR scan of a bus card will take you to the following:

www.site_url.com/_brad

It's a specific error (I know the / is missing and should be ../_brad/).

But you end up getting a 404 - of course.

Can I take that error and redirect to:
www.site_url.com/_brad/index.html

Here's what I've tried... (not working)

RewriteRule ^(.*)_brad(.*)$ /_brad/index.html

Do I need a RewriteCond ??

Thanks for any help you can provide. Forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Do you have `RewriteEngine On` set before your RewriteRule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/_brad  /_brad/index.html [R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks ultrnaut! Doesn't seem to be working. We are working with a Prestashop store. I added the code, and the RewriteEngine On but we still get redirected when using the phone. Let me try a cache dump.

Comment: What url is it that you end up at exactly? Are you able to trace the http requests to see what the sequence of redirects is?

Comment: the end url is .http://www.zukudla.com/_brad/index.html
Using cPanel at Siteground, it included the following in the htaccess file 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^zukudla\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.zukudla\.com$
RewriteRule ^_brad\/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.zukudla\.com\/_brad\/" [R=301,L]

Comment: Even using Siteground redirect function in cPanel, I'm still getting the 404. Doesn't matter if our store is enabled or disabled.

Comment: I've loaded a few other QR scanners and am testing. Some working and some not. I'm thinking this is less of a redirect issue and more on the scanner end. I really appreciate your help!! I think I will move onto other more pressing issues now. Cheers!